Why does exception stops the main loop despite having try-except block?
I have the following code:
import datetime
import logging
import time

import pychromecast

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(threadName)s:%(message)s")


def run():
    id = 'sony kd-49xh8505'
    cast = pychromecast.get_chromecast_from_host(
        host=("192.168.86.126", None, id, id, id)
    )
    cast.wait()
    logging.info(cast.status.display_name)


while True:
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    try:
        run()
    except Exception as e:
        print("recovering")
    time.sleep(0.5)

As you can see, I want to check every 0.5 second what app is running on my TV using PyChromecast. I want to ignore all errors and proceed with the loop.
The sample output is:
2024-09-15 19:33:48.253462
MainThread:YouTube
2024-09-15 19:33:49.171936
MainThread:YouTube
2024-09-15 19:33:50.165728
MainThread:YouTube
2024-09-15 19:33:51.090723
Thread-38:[(192.168.86.126):8009] Failed to connect to service HostServiceInfo(host='192.168.86.126', port=8009), retrying in 5.0s

So the app if working fine, then some connection error occurs and the app stops. The while True loop stops. What's interesting:

the main loop stops, but doesn't breaks (the app process is still active), but no further actions are performed
I have try-except: print("recovering"), but this message is not in the output
the log "Failed to connect to service" originates in a different thread - "Thread-38" - instead of "MainThread".
Note also that the message says "retrying in 5.0s", but nothing happens after 5 seconds.

Could you please explain what's happening here and - even more important - how to modify my app to ignore all connection errors and simply proceed with the main loop?

Why does the output print "MainThread:Youtube"? I don't see such a statement. Is the output really the output of the given code?

Does cast.wait() ever return? It could be waiting for the dead thread.

You can't catch exceptions from other threads. You can only catch exceptions from the thread which has the try/except block

To answer below question.

How to modify my app to ignore all connection errors and simply proceed with the main loop?

The log output you shared specifically references Thread-38, which indicates that the connection error is happening in a separate thread from the MainThread. This suggests that pychromecast is using additional threads to manage communication. Here's the log.
Thread-38:[(192.168.86.126):8009] Failed to connect to service HostServiceInfo(host='192.168.86.126', port=8009), retrying in 5.0s

I tried retrying logic to catch errors, so we aren't dependent on the internal Chromecast threads to recover automatically. It might not be the best way to handle the question but this will eventually work.
def run():
    id = 'sony kd-49xh8505'
    try:
        cast = pychromecast.get_chromecast_from_host(
            host=("192.168.86.126", None, id, id, id)
        )
        cast.wait(timeout=5)  # Wait for Chromecast to be ready with a timeout
        logging.info(cast.status.display_name)  # Print the current app

    except pychromecast.ChromecastConnectionError:
        logging.error("Chromecast connection failed, retrying...")
        return False  # Indicate failure to reconnect

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Unexpected error occurred: {e}")
        return False  # Handle other exceptions

    return True  # Return True if the connection is successful


while True:
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    
    success = run()  # Attempt to run the connection
    
    if not success:
        print("Failed to connect, retrying after 5 seconds...")
        time.sleep(5)  # Wait before retrying in case of failure
    
    time.sleep(0.5)  # Continue looping

handle the exception in the run itself.
I hope that is helpful.

And how exactly shall this help? If Chromecast opens a new thread, your try/catch will still be on the wrong thread.

OP asked " how to modify my app to ignore all connection errors and simply proceed with the main loop?".
update 1:
retry logic with catching errors, so we aren't dependent on the internal chromecast threads to recover automatically

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I updated the answer per community guidelines.

Your exception block is not working due to pychromecasts inner handling.
Looking at error it creates a thread with a try catch block inside of it and when a error happens it waits and tres to reconnect. This behavior causes no exceptions to be thrown outside run command rendering your catch not working.
Since they alread created a wait and try to reconnect behavior inside pychromecast and it seems to be working contuonusly can you try your run command outside while and try catch

Just to follow-up: indeed there was a inner error handling in pychromecast, configurable in this way
            cast = pychromecast.get_chromecast_from_host(
                host=(self.ip, None, self.id, self.id, self.id),
                tries=1,
                retry_wait=0,
                timeout=5.0
            )


I'd recommend adding the link to the documentation where you found the properties could be added.  This'll help the user self solve in the future.
